# OpenSSL provide private key as string

Tags: openssl, rsa

In [OpenSSL 3.0](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-rsautl.html) is it possible to provide the private key for decryption as a string.
I want to store the key inside some database and not as a file. Therefore i want to call OpenSSL with the key as a string not with the filepath.

I use windows and then run OpenSSL with the shell. The key is stored as in PEM format.

I now want to execute OpenSSL like in this bash script.

```
key="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
<key data>
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

command="openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey $key -in license.enc -keyform PEM"
eval $command
```

So far I couldn't get it running and on the [RSA OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-rsautl.html) page i saw no such option.
But maybe someone has some solution for this.

Comment: Databases generally have support for VARBINARY, so I'm not sure why you cannot store binary directly. The only useful text in PEM (see my answer) is ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY, but I would assume that would be apparent from the table definition.

Comment: I don't think that the OpenSSL CLI has what you are looking for. Maybe using a temporary file on a [volume mounted using  `tmpfs`](https://askubuntu.com/q/152868/52628) can help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `-keyform PEM`. PEM stands for Privacy Enhanced Mail, i.e. it is explicitly designed for textual interfaces.

You would get text file that starts with:

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
<Base64 encoded encrypted private key>
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The actual encoding is specified in [RFC 5958: Asymmetric Key Packages](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5958).

---

Beware that this is an old standard, you want to use PBES2, a strong password and a high iteration count, specified during key (pair) generation.

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself incorrectly. I already have a PEM key and i know want to decrypt something with this PEM, without saving it in a extra file.
Like this:

`key="-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
<Base64 encoded encrypted private key>
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----"`

`openssl rsautl  -inkey $key -in license.enc`

Comment: Ah, OK, right. In the end OpenSSL as you are using is just a CLI, why not actually program it in e.g. C (or any other language that supports encrypted PKCS#8 files)?

Comment: That's a good point. I was thinking about this as well. But I was trying for some quick solution first.